# Fancybox2 - Images load, but php pages don't

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have this code if I am using an Image gallery;

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="fancybox">Image1</a>
```

At the bottom of the HTML code, I have this code (after Adding the CSS and Fancybox JS)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

BOOM! Magic, it works and shows the image in a nice Fancybox window..

Now if I have this:

```
<a href="mypage.php" class="fancybox">My page</a>
```

It will just redirect to mypage.php normally, but it wont show it in a nice fancybox window... I just don't get it, I've followed the examples they give in the official Fancybox site, still nothing working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open php file in fancy box use something like this

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="mypage.php">Ajax</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

and read the example url here

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
```

Comment: where does the `href="uitab/index.html"` come from? (copy/paste I guess ;)

Comment: please check i have edit this to mypage.php and sorry for copy/paste :-) because i answer this many times :-)